# OpenLayers 3 and Windows XP

Tags: firefox, opengl-es, webgl, openlayers-3

Currently, I use Openlayers 3 (the last vesion of OL3) with Windows XP Professional.
My PC has features as below:

- Intrl Processor (R) Pentium (R) 4 CPU 3.00Ghz (2CPUs)
- 1GB Memory
- DirectX Version: DirectX 9.0c (4.09.0000.0904)
- Graphics: Intel (R) 82945G Express Chipset Family
- Display mode: 1280 * 1024 (32bit).
- Browser: Mozilla Firefox 47.0.1

My problem, the map does not appear (I use the card BingMap with key).
The error appears as follows:

```
Error: WebGL: Error during ANGLE OpenGL init. ol.js:112:304
Error: WebGL: Refused to create native OpenGL context because of blacklisting. ol.js:112:304
Error: WebGL: WebGL creation failed. ol.js:112:304
Error: WebGL: Error during ANGLE OpenGL init. ol.js:112:304
Error: WebGL: Refused to create native OpenGL context because of blacklisting. ol.js:112:304
Error: WebGL: WebGL creation failed.
```

Is there a relationship with the configuration of my PC this error? . How will do to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the canvas renderer instead of the WebGL renderer (renderer: 'canvas' on the ol.Map, but this should be the default already, are you specifying 'webgl') ?

Comment: To display the map, I use ** renderer: canvas **. then I write on the address bar to check the activation of webgl **webglreport.com** and I see that the WEBGL is not activated yet. I activate the webgl in **about: config** and put the **false** value **true** for **webgl.force-enabled** and **false** in **true** for **webgl.disable-angle**. No change

Comment: Finally, the map is displayed after updating my browser (firefox 48.0.2) and I actively WEBGL 2.0 (webgl.enable-ptototype-webgl2).
But the error remains on the console as follows: **Error: WebGL: Error during native OpenGL init. ol.js:112:304
Error: WebGL: WebGL creation failed. ol.js:112:304**

Answer (score 0):

To display the map, I use **renderer: canvas** as the following code:

```
 var map = new ol.Map({
                layers: [layer.AerialWithLabels],
                renderer: 'canvas',
                target: 'view-container',
                view:  new ol.View({ center: [0, 0], resolution: 39135.75848201024, minZoom: 2 })
            });
```

then I write on the address bar to check the activation of webgl **webglreport.com** and I see that the WEBGL is not activated yet.
I activate the webgl in **about: config** and put the  **false** value **true** for **webgl.force-enabled** and  **false**  in **true** for **webgl.disable-angle**

I update my page and error:

```
Error: WebGL: Error during native OpenGL init. ol.js:112:304
Error: WebGL: WebGL creation failed. ol.js:112:304
Error: WebGL: Error during native OpenGL init. ol.js:112:304
Error: WebGL: WebGL creation failed.
```